# Edit apache environment path in OS X 10.10 Server

Tags: apache-2.4, mac-osx-server, environment-variables, path, phpinfo

My phpinfo displays that the Environment Path for Apache is:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I would like to add:

```
/opt/local/bin/
```

I'm using OS X 10.10 Server with the Website functionality of the Server.app